# Windows Task Scheduler EXE log file not generating

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler

I have scheduled an EXE and in that I wrote a code to save all logs in a file. When I run that project locally, the logs are generated but when the exe is scheduled in task scheduler the log file is not generated. I checked my debug folder path but the file is not generated there. I checked this path as well : `C:\\Windows\System32\ScheduleProcessing_Errors`. But it is not generated there either.

This is how I am writing the logs:

```
public static void WriteErrorLog(string MsgBody, string innerexp, string Caller, string MethodName)
        {
            try
            {
                string Path;
                string Todaydate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Path = Application.StartupPath + "\\ScheduleProcessing_Errors";
                if (Directory.Exists(Path) == false)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
                }
                Path += "\\NewLogToFindMyErr" + Todaydate + ".txt";
                StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Path, true);
                SW.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);                
                SW.WriteLine(Caller + "\t" + MethodName + "\t" + MsgBody + "\t" + innerexp);
                SW.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                SW.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
                
                SW.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                SW.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

While you setup the task scheduler, chose Run Whether the user logged in or not, and opt=> Do not store password. It will give access to computer local resources